# Intent Filter passing data through url and reading into activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, intentfilter

In my app, I need to open one page from out side app, through link which is in email.

In my app when some one will create post from our website then we are sending email with `url`.

When user will click on `url/link` then it will open respective page in the app.

I need to pass some id and other value to the activity when it launch.

Example:

we are sending following link through email when some one create post on website.

```
https://www.example.com/lt-url-redirector.php?user_guid=4074395&notify_entity_id=7221752&notification_type=22&notify_id=56933b6219b05172&baseurl=https://www.example.com/groups/calendar/aggregation/mlt
```

After clicking on above link it goes to mobile browser where "Open in App" button is there.

After taping on this button it gives:

```
window.location.href = 'abcdef:/?user_guid=4074395&notify_entity_id=7221752&notification_type=22&notify_id=56933b6219b05172&baseurl=https://www.example.com/groups/calendar/aggregation/mlt';
```

I want to pass notify_entity_id, notification_type, notify_id etc to the activity when it launch.

Android Manifest code :

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="abcdef" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: my question is how to read data href (when browser button is clicked) into activity which is opened by this button.

Answer (score 0):

Those are query parameters, and there are a variety of methods on `Uri` for retrieving those values, [such as `getQueryParameters()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameters(java.lang.String)). To get the `Uri`, call `getIntent().getData()` from some likely spot, such as `onCreate()` of your activity.