# How to authenticate with Google and redirect to Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-drive-api, phonegap

I am trying to upload and download files from Google Drive. For that I intent to use Google Drive API, but authentication is required.

Here are a few problems to begin with:
1.) Google+ recently got shut down, so usage of the plugin `cordova-plugin-googleplus` (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) is no more useful.
2.) There are some questions asked across the web relating to the same problem, but none of them are helpful, very old, or simply vague and not properly answered.

The problem is: How do I redirect to my app after the authentication is done and STILL be able to get all the necessary tokens? I was thinking about the universal deep linking on Android to do it but I am not sure if will work.

In general, I really need help with the overall flow of the authentication or some resources which can help me do it using Javascript only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect users back into my app after google oauth without using a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988942/how-can-i-redirect-users-back-into-my-app-after-google-oauth-without-using-a-web)

Comment: Also check https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp under **Alternatives**